# Is it possible to use pin authentication for sanction (Oauth)?

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0

The [docs](http://sanction.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) make no mention of pin-authentication that I can see. ([No search results](http://sanction.readthedocs.org/en/latest/search.html?q=pin&check_keywords=yes&area=default))

Is it possible using sanction?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is:

```
client_pin = ''
client_id = 'your_client_id'
client_secret = 'your_client_secret'
request_token = 'some_random_state_hash'

client_pin = input('Enter PIN:')

access_token_url = 'https://api.home.nest.com/oauth2/access_token'

c = Client(
    token_endpoint=access_token_url_plain,
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret)

c.request_token(code = client_pin)
```

You should now have a session.